# MathJax inconsistency between preview and rendered post

Tags: discussion, markdown-preview, mathjax

I cannot show it here or in the Sandbox directly since there is no MathJax on Meta.SE. There is a Sandbox in [Cryptgraphy Meta](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1582/18298) that one can test there; just click edit and see the difference. The problematic line is:

`**Formula:** $\mathbf{Adv}^{ind-cca3}_{\pi}(A)=Pr\left[K\overset{\$}{\leftarrow}\mathcal{K}:A^{\mathcal{E}_K(\cdot),\mathcal{D}_K(\cdot)}\Rightarrow 1\right] - Pr\left[A^{\mathcal{E}_K(\$|\cdot|),\perp(\cdot)}\Rightarrow 1\right] $`

It is rendered correctly in the preview, however, when the page is saved, it seems there is a constraint on the size so that the last power gets two lines.

From the user's perspective, this inconsistency is annoying since we can only see it after saving and we need to consider alternative solutions to solve it, like making it small in size, breaking with newlines, etc.

Can we make this consistent?

**update**: I've [tested](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1582/18298) with making a new line for the formulae with `$$....$$` and `\small{....}`

---

#### Preview

[image: MathJax post preview]

#### Saved

[image: Fully rendered post, with power wrapping on two lines]

---

None of the proposed workarounds have solved this issue. It seems to be something other than the length issue.

Comment: Well the server and client side preview are two different things, and that's the problem here, as is with other places.

Comment: @Luuklag I've figured out that It is not really a width problem, there is another issue with this. Tested it in the [Crypto's sandbox](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1582/18298)

Comment: No idea about mathjax, but in latex the syntax `\small{...}` does not make much sense. `\small` is a switch and does not take an argument. Also don't set multi-letter expressions like `ind-cca3` in math mode, the kerning is messed up.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz multi-letter expressions are very common in modern cryptography that we cannot get rid of. Why does it mess with the latex kernel?

Comment: @kelalaka There is no problem with using multi-letter experessions, just don't use math mode for them. if you load the `amsmath` package, you can input them as `\text{ind-cca3}` to get the correct kerning.